# What happens to recurring work when the device is off?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

While using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), I could not find the documentation for an expected behavior:

Suppose I scheduled an hourly task, and the device was shutdown from 16:00 to 08:00, then, after the device reboots, what happens?

Is it deferred until the device starts back up at? Or is it "skipped" until the next scheduled date?

I would also appreciate any documentation, if available.